# No Longer Able to Access App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I've been using Google App Maker for a few months now, but tried to log into an existing App today and am getting this error:

[image]

The published app still seems to be working. But, I tested two different admin accounts to try and edit it and both get the same error. I looked under the G Suites Admin Panel and don't see App Maker in the G Suite Apps or Additional Google Services section.

Who do I need to contact? Should I submit something to the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:192783%2B%20type:bug)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If App Maker is no longer showing in your Admin Console then it seems there is a problem with your G Suite account. There are other reports in the App Maker Google Group from other users who are also reporting something similar hence I believe this is a bug. Please don't use Issue Trackers since this is mainly used to report bugs or issues found inside the App Maker service.

You must contact G Suite Support to report this since this an issues associated with the services inside the Admin Console. There is an App Maker Team in G Suite Support that will be able to help on this. More info on how to contact G Suite is available here https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. My problem was I had two google accounts (personal and business). For some reason even if I was logged into my business account, when I went to appmaker.google.com the accounts would switch and I would be shown the please apply for early adopter page. To get around this logout of your personal account, clear cache, login with account that has access and you should be taken to the appmaker welcome screen.